# GridView for asp.net AJAX

Tags: asp.net

Is there a ajax Gridview and pager Control for asp.net that you can download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotnetSlackers have an open source project with a grid (featuring paging) based on asp.net ajax...

http://dotnetslackers.com/projects/AjaxDataControls/